# Creating list from selected data from panda series with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, list

I want to identify the character "AD" in the first element of my pandas.core.series.Series and then take the values in the same position of the following elements of this pandas series in order to create a list with these values.

```
# This is my pandas.core.series.Series
df.iloc[0, 8:]

FORMAT                 GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL
1165684808    0/1:7,7:14:99:131,0,131
369966783     0/1:6,8:14:99:141,0,107
373977569     0/0:18,0:18:54:0,54,442
373977829       0/0:6,0:6:18:0,18,148
373977873     0/0:12,0:12:36:0,36,297
373978069     0/0:14,0:14:42:0,42,346
373978077       0/0:8,0:8:24:0,24,198
373978079     0/0:14,0:14:42:0,42,346
373978129          0/0:2,0:2:6:0,6,48
373978131     0/0:14,0:14:42:0,42,346
373978148     0/0:13,0:13:39:0,39,321
373978159       0/0:8,0:8:24:0,24,198
373978276       0/0:8,0:8:24:0,24,198
373978284     0/0:12,0:12:36:0,36,297
373978296           0/0:0,0:0:.:0,0,0
373978307       0/0:6,0:6:18:0,18,148
373978311     0/0:12,0:12:36:0,36,297
373978317       0/0:6,0:6:18:0,18,148
373978320     0/0:16,0:16:48:0,48,387
373978323     0/0:18,0:18:48:0,48,720
373978346       0/0:8,0:8:24:0,24,198
373978353     0/0:12,0:12:30:0,30,450
373978581     0/0:14,0:14:36:0,36,540
373978640     0/0:19,0:19:57:0,57,470
```

Desire output

```
"7,7", "6,8", "18,0", ... , "19,0"
```

Comment: `[i.split(':')[1] for i in df['GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL']]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want this?

```
result = df['GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL'].str.strip().str.split(':').str[1].values
```

**output:**

```
array(['7,7', '6,8', '18,0', '6,0', '12,0', '14,0', '8,0', '14,0', '2,0',
       '14,0', '13,0', '8,0', '8,0', '12,0', '0,0', '6,0', '12,0', '6,0',
       '16,0', '18,0', '8,0', '12,0', '14,0', '19,0'], dtype=object)
```